# Carnot Cycle with adiabats crossing on $pV$ diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, adiabatic, volume

So my Thermodynamics teacher said that on a  $pV$ diagram, you can get adiabats crossing for a Carnot cycle, even if all the possible thermodynamic states of the system can be represented on a  $pV$ diagram (2 dimensions). So this is NOT the case where a third state variable is needed to define the state of the system.
However, since the Carnot cycle is reversible, the adiabats on the  $pV$ diagram are isentropic processes. So how can these adiabats cross? Because the point of intersection must have either one entropy or the other, because entropy is a state function.

He said this can happen with things like water, which has the same density at a certain sub-zero temperature and then at a certain above-zero temperature, so at some point there is a maximum in one of the state variables.

He said that on some occasions, the  $pV$ diagram is not useful in representing the processes because of this matter of lines crossing, and that another 2D diagram would be clearer.

Well, how can the adiabats cross? What could produce this situation?

Comment: The reversible adiabatic processes in the Carnot cycle  do not intersect. They connect the reversible isothermal processes. Don't know where your teacher got that idea. Is there more context?